# не работает router-view в vue проекте

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, router

не работает роутер просто не видит наверное, я уж не знаю в чем проблема помогите пожалуйста путь установлен роутеры включены
картинки по порядку

1. файл `index.js` главный файл `router'ов`
2. файл `main.js` отсюда начинается работа проекта
3. файл `App.vue` в нем проимпортирован компонент `v-main-wrapper` он то нам и нужен
4. файл `v-main-wrapper` это последнее что видит `vue` а дальше все но вот тут и стоит `router-view` и он не работает помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему

[image: файл index.js главный файл router'ов]

[image: файл main.js отсюда начинается работа проекта]

[image: файл App.vue в нем проимпортирован компонент v-main-wrapper он то нам и нужен]

[image: файл v-main-wrapper это последнее что видит vue а дальше все но вот тут и стоит router-view и он не работает помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему]

Answer (score 0):

У ваc в конфиге роутера неправильно название поля самих роутов написано. Замените *routers* на *routes*.